# search on Long value in Database with CriteriaBuilder

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate, jpa

im trying to search for an "Order" in my "Order"-table in my database, and i'm not finding it because of the get() method, which accepts just strings and not long values. 
Here is the code:

```
  public List<OrderItemEntity> findOrderItem(OrderItem orderitem){
    long id = orderitem.getId();
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    try {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<OrderItemEntity> cq = cb.createQuery(OrderItemEntity.class);
        Root<OrderItemEntity> root = cq.from(OrderItemEntity.class);
        cq.where(cb.equal(root.get("id"), String.valueOf(id))); <<---- THIS LINE!!
        TypedQuery query = em.createQuery(cq);
        List<OrderItemEntity> result = query.getResultList();
        System.out.println("orderID found is: " + result.get(0).getId());
        return result;
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

can anyone help? How could I cast that "id" in a string value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If id is your primary id it would be easier to just find your entity with:

```
OrderItemEntity myitem = em.find(OrderItemEntity.class, id);
```

Alternatively, use select method in your query and everything should work fine (String.valueof should you are using is OK):

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<OrderItemEntity> cq = cb.createQuery(OrderItemEntity.class);
    Root<OrderItemEntity> root = cq.from(OrderItemEntity.class);
    cq.select( root );
    cq.where(cb.equal(root.get("id"), String.valueOf(id))); 
    TypedQuery query = em.createQuery(cq);
    List<OrderItemEntity> result = query.getResultList()
```

Comment: yes it is my primary id noted with @Id Tag on Java Class. But it doesn't work with em.find! Could you perhaps help with the other alternative? just how to convert that long to string or something like that..?

Comment: Check the updated answer and tell me if it works now

Comment: no, im still getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException at the println line. 
So the result list is an empty list, although it shouldnt be and the order exists in the db.. :/ but thx for your help! danke ;-)